# Запуск Turbo C++ без эмулятора

Tags: c++

Как запустить Turbo C++ без эмулятора на win 7 x64?

Comment: Никак. Даже под WinXP досовские программы запускаются под эмулятором (не DOSBox, конечно, а NTVDM)

Comment: Вообще в 2012 году запуск Turbo C++ может иметь отношение только к хобби. Если вы фанат трупного цеплюсплюс, то чем мешает эмулятор? Если не фанат -- зачем turbo c++?

Comment: Или в учебных целях, но и в этом случаи эмулятор ничем не мешает.

Comment: Ну в учебных целях от таких штук лучше держаться подальше. Это скорее всего первое издание Страуструпа (темплетов ещё не было), да к тому же подправленное Борландом. Не надо портить мозги учащихся.

Comment: Тем не менее, в некоторых учебных заведениях применяется.

Comment: Сказать тут можно много, но закон против высказывания оценок такими словами.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/turbocforwindows-9/ первая ссылка в гугле. Подойдет?

Answer (score 3):

Можно виртуальную машину `Windows 98` установить. Эмулятор `windows` почти ничем не ограничивает, единственное, что пока вспомнил, это отсутствует прямой доступ к устройствам, например к `com` и `lpt` портам.

Если у вас графика не работает, то это компилятор не может найти файл графического драйвера `egavga.bgi`. Нужно либо в коде указывать его вместе с путем, либо в настройках компилятора указать соотв. папку. Можно в папку `bin` скопировать, там его компилятор должен найти.

Comment: А если можно виртуальную win98, то почему нельзя виртуальную dos?

Comment: Можно, эти версии для `dos`. Но новичку, думаю, больший интерес представляет графическая оболочка `windows 98`, чем командная строка `dos`, даже если он умеет на нем работать.